# SINR calculation

Tags: matlab, modulation, real-time, snr

I would like to calculate the total SINR of a IQ modulation system in time domain.
$$ SINR = \frac{P}{N+I}$$
The blocks of the system are.

- Bit generation
- QAM modulation
- pulse shaper (sq root raised cosine f)
- IQ mod
- IQ dem
- filter (root raised)
- QAM demodulation

[image]

I made a simulation of a IQ modulation system in time domain, with a recovery of the signal, but unfortunately I dunno how to calculate the SNIR.

[Here is the file, thanks for your help.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/l263s1o2n2ln3n6/IQ_transmission.rar)

The main file is `my_modem.m`.

Here you can see the outputs!
http://matlabonline.p.ht/

Comment: Crosspost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528453/sinr-calculation

Comment: Christian: Welcome to DSP.SE!  Please do not cross-post to multiple SE sites. Choose one. If another is more appropriate, the mods will migrate it.  Also, please take **some** time to format your question. Cutting and pasting without sensible editing makes it look bad. Better editing usually results in better answers.

Comment: If this is a simulation, then the only noise and interference should be noise and interference that you have added.  I'm not quite sure what you are asking for.

Comment: Dear Jim, even though I haven't add noise or interference to the simulation, I am just trying to find a way to measure them at the **receiver**.

Please check the code with functions  [here](http://matlabonline.com)

Comment: @JimClay, please check the simulation [here](http://matlabonline.p.ht)

Answer (score 1):

If there *was* intersymbol interference or additive noise in your simulation you could calculate the noise term by taking the difference of the transmit signal $x(k)$ (before pulse shaper) and the received signal $r(k)$ (after sampler):
$$
n(k) = r(k) - x(k),
$$

where $k$ is the discrete time and is omitted in the following. Computation of the signal to interference and noise ratio (SINR) is then straightforward:
$$
\gamma_\mathrm{SINR} = \frac{\mathrm E[|x|^2]}{\mathrm E[|n|^2]} = \frac{\sum_{k} |x|^2}{\sum_{k} |n|^2}
$$

$\mathrm E[]$ is the expectation operator.

In your simulation, $x$ corresponds to *input signal* and $r$ to *filtered signal*.